# hadoop eclipse plugin not deploying code to hadoop cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any place where i can find how to configure hadoop eclipse plugin which comes with hadoop download.?

I have hadoop running on a linux sandbox in vmware player. I got this preinstalled hadoop image from yahoo developer network. My hadoop is running and i am able to connect to the sandbox from my host machine through putty/winscp to start hadoop or to transfer files to hdfs. I tried to configure the eclipse hadoop plugin, but for some reason i am not able to connect to the sandbox.

or, Is there any other hadoop development plugin/option available. i got a windows machine.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem also, and **tried different versions of eclipse**, finally got a working pair.

It's painful...

Comment: What version of hadoop plugin is working with which version of eclipse. You should include this.